# UILable iPhone

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

Мне надо проверить любые изменеия в UILable. Если оно изменилось то продалжать работу если нет остановить ее, кто-то может подсказать как это сделать. Я пробовал чере BOOL но не совсем понимаю как это будет выглядить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сомневаюсь, что `UILabel` имеет делегатские методы на изменение.
Я бы положил на лейбл какой-нибудь `UITextField` и обработка что-то вроде:

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad
        {
             [textField setDelegate:self];
        }

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
        {
            if([notification object] == textField)
            {
                NSLog(@"The contents of the text field changed");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Идея помогла, спасибо !